# "Laragon" Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.15-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\intl

Tags: php, apache, laragon

I just start a new project and have to switch from ***WAMP*** to ***Laragon***.
Everything was good until I change the path of my "***php***" from ***C:\wamp64\bin\php*** to ***C:\laragon\bin\php***.
When I try this command on my terminal ***php -v*** I have this message

> **Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.15-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\intl (Le module
> sp├®cifi├® est introuvable.),
> C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.15-Win32-VC15-x64/ext\php_intl.dll (Le
> module sp├®cifi├® est introuvable.)) in Unknown on line 0** PHP 7.4.15
> (cli) (built: Feb  2 2021 20:47:45) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend
> Technologies

So basically my path isn't recognized.
Here is what I tried

1. check in the php.ini from Laragon the path ***extension_dir =  "C:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.4.15-Win32-VC15-x64/ext"*** and compare to mine which is the same ***C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.15-Win32-VC15-x64\ext***.
2. I tried this solution [with oracle](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/607/tutorial-how-to-install-php-s-oracle-oci-extension/3)
3. I tried this solution about [visual studio](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/1088/warning-on-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php_intl-dll/12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved with :
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe.

Just installed this and reboot Laragon and my command php -v work well i don't any error !